# Expression Engine Sidebar Nav issue post migration

Tags: apache2, expressionengine

I am a novice with EE but I am working in an environment where we migrated the EE from one host to another and post-migration I am having an issue with the nav bar where it is displaying code:

```
$nav): $class = ($nav['url_title'] == 'about-us') ? ' class="current"' : ''; echo ''.$nav['title'].''; if($nav['url_title'] == 'about-us'): ?>Company Overview
Our History
'; endforeach; ?>
```

Screenshots located here:  http://www.evernote.com/l/AAMKcm-337JD3o9Wv2L6kmDUk6eCGA1Sbd0/

Any thoughts?  This is not occurring on the original server.

Comment: You could make this a better question if you could post code from the template, not just what you are seeing in the browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that your old host had [short_open_tag](http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phptags.php) turned on in php.ini while your new host does not.

You could fix this either by turning short_open_tags on in your .ini file or replacing `<?` with `<?php` in your template.

Would also check to confirm that php parsing is turned on in the template and the it is called at the expected parsing stage (input or output -- based on your snipped am guessing you need 'output').

Answer (score 1):

Not 100% sure, but my guess would be that your old server was running PHP 5.4+, and your new server is < PHP 5.4. PHP 5.4 brought array shorthand syntax, and your new server seems it might not support it?

Hope this helps!